# How to check if an array has squared elements of another array (regardless of order)?

Tags: java

a = [121, 144, 19, 161, 19, 144, 19, 11]
b = [121, 14641, 20736, 361, 25921, 361, 20736, 361]
returns true, coz b[] has squared values of elements in a[], regardless of order.

Here's what I tried...

```
static boolean comp(int a[], int b[]) {
        int x = 0;
        if (a.equals(b)) {
            for (int i : a) {
                for (int j : b) {
                    if (a[i] == b[j] * b[j]) {
                        x++;
                    } else {
                        x--;
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
        if (x == a.length) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does it have to contain the square of _all_ of the elements from `a`, or if it has at least one is it true?

Comment: There are a few problems with your code. Your first `if` condition should be `a.equals(b) == false`. Your `for loops` are iterating over elements of the arrays `a` or `b`, not indices of the array. Not sure about what the counting is supposed to do, but I would assume that you want to have a `square`of every element in b. However simple counting won't solve this issue (in case there are multiple squares in b). Decrementing seems just wrong.

Comment: Also if `a` and `b` would be equal, its not necessarily `false`. Consider `a` and `b` beeing `[1]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
static boolean comp(int a[], int b[]) {

    for (int i : a) {
        if (!Arrays.asList(b).contains(i*i)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply this would work:

```
static boolean comp(int a[], int b[]) {

    for (int i : a) {
        if (!Arrays.asList(b).contains(i*i)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

In short, you go through every value of a and b to see if the value of a squared is b. When you find a non-match, you automatically return false. Otherwise, true is returned.

Comment: You return when you find the first one.  The OP wants to know if all the elements, when squared, are in the other list.

Comment: @ML72: even after the edit you seem to solve a different problem. Nobody stated that every element in `b` needs to be a square of every element in `a`.

Answer (score 1):

```java
public static Boolean compare(int[] a, int[] b) {
  Arrays.sort(a);
  Arrays.sort(b);
  for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (a[i] * a[i] != b[i]) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`List` has a [`containsAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#containsAll-java.util.Collection-), I would use that; with Java 8+ and streams that might look like

```
static boolean comp(int a[], int b[]) {
    return Arrays.stream(b).distinct().boxed().collect(Collectors.toList())
            .containsAll(Arrays.stream(a).map(x -> x * x).boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.toList()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try sorting both arrays and iterating over both of them at the same, first squaring the number from the first array and then checking if it is equal to the element from the second array. Once you reach non-equal elements return false, otherwise return true. This should give you 2*n*log(n) + n if using quicksort.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static Boolean compare(int[] a, int[] b) {
  Arrays.sort(a);
  Arrays.sort(b);
  for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (a[i] * a[i] != b[i]) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

```
bool Same(int[] arr1, int[] arr2)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < arr1.Length; i++)
    {
        var correctIndex = Array.IndexOf(arr2, (int)Math.Pow(arr1[i], 2));
        if (correctIndex == -1)
        {
            return false;
        }
        arr2.Take(correctIndex);
    }
    return true;
}

in c#
```